# Can i create and show a DatePickerFragment from FragmentActivity or Fragment?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

So,

I have a FragmentActivity with multiple tabs.My tabs are static Fragments, this is simply what eclipse created when i Added this activity.

Now in one of my tabs i want a button that will show a DatePickerDialog. My understanding is that i create a class like so,

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

public DatePickerFragment(){
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //Default dagsetning er i dag.
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),HomeScreenFragment.OnDateSet(year,month,day),year,month,day;
    }
}
```

Well the docs say that the second parameter in DatePickerDialog constructor is

> "callBack  How the parent is notified that the date is set."

So i tried to implement that callback in my static Fragment class that holds the button. inside the buttons onclick method i wrote:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
newFragment.show(fm, "dialog");
```

But Eclipse says,

> The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)

So i'm confused. I'm passing show the parameters it wants but it does not recognize them.
Any ideas? Is it a bad idea or maybe not possible to create and show my DatePickerFragment from the tab Fragment i have?

Also, why do i need to import all this android.support.v4.app.Fragment stuff when my minSdkVersion is 11 and target is 18? I thought it was for backwards compatability pre android 11 but if i try just importing for example android.app.Fragment, i get all types of errors?

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you probably imported the stuff from the supportLib -  that starts with android.support....

Don't extend FragmentActivity since its also from the supportLib, but simply extend Activity in API11+. It can already handle Fragments.

You either have to take all the Fragment stuff from the supportLib, or nothing. Mixing it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so i tried simply extending Activity but then in the eclipse genarated code i got an error in thiss class variable,

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

Comment: Ok - so the generated stuff some needs more things from the support libs- You could also go in the other direction - only use the Fragment stuff from the support Library. Extend FragmentActivity again and don't import DialogFragment from android.app, but from android.support.... in your DatePicker. This has another advantage that you can already use the new stuff like nested fragments, that exists in the support lib, but not in the API 11 Fragments. Just don't mix it.

Comment: Yeah, i googled some more and most people agreed that using the support lib is easiest. Cleaned it all and got it working. Thanks for your support!